# Perl dancer validation at serverside

Tags: perl, dancer

I am creating a web application using Perl dancer. I am stuck at the validation part. I have a specific validation rule for each field and if the entered value is not within the rules the text in the field should be highlighted in red. I am using data::FormValidator for the server side validation. My questions are :

- Can I write user specific validation rules with Data::FormValidator if not is there any modules that i can use for this
- how to display the errors as html rather than using DataDumper.

Comment: The CGI module works with the command `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to dump fatal errors in HTML format. I don't know what PSGI offers in that department.

Comment: have you tried template toolkit for displaying your errors nicely? Dancer also has its own native simplified templating tool